# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int (*)(int, int, int, int, int)' from 'int *'

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have this pointer to an orgFunction takes 5 int as input and returns int, and orgfunctionhook takes the same args and return:

```
int (*orgFunction)(int a1, int a2 , int a3 , int a4, int a5);

int orgFunctionHook(int a1, int a2 , int a3 , int a4, int a5)
{
  // do something..
  return orgFunction(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5);
}

void Load(){
    orgFunction = (int*)HookFunction((char*)"something", 0x50000, (void*)orgFunctionHook);
}
```

And the HookFunction takes 3 args, const char, an address for my original function, and some hook

for ease this is the definition for it:

```
void* HookFunction(char* path, uint64_t vaddr, void* replace);
```

it returns a void*, my function i want to use it return int, once i use it in the Load()

I get this error:

```
" Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int (*)(int, int, int, int, int)' from 'int *' "
```

My attempt to solve it was to declare it like this:

```
void Load(){
    void * orgFunction = (int*)HookFunction((char*)"something", 0x50000, (void*)orgFunctionHook);
}
```

but this makes a problem in the run time it when it runs the orgFunctionHook, the pointer address to the function orgFunction will be assinged as 0x0 ( EMPTY )

Is there could be another solution to pass this without losing the pointer to the origin function?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, that I can't change anything related to the HookFunction, its return or paramters remain the same.

Comment: the error is clear. You're assigning an `int*` to `int (*)(int, int, int, int, int)`. Why do you cast the result to `int*`?

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: @phuclv Because the output of the hookfunction should be int as it takes as parameter a function that returns int

Comment: @JasonLiam I tried searching, the problems are not very similar to this problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting to the wrong type.  As mentioned in the error message, the function pointer has type `int (*)(int,int,int,int,int)` but you're attempting to assign an expression of type `int *` to it.  These types are incompatible.

The proper way to do this would be to create a typedef for the function pointer type:

```
typedef int (*ftype)(int, int, int, int, int);
```

Then you declare your function pointer with this type:

```
ftype orgFunction;
```

And similarly with `HookFunction`:

```
ftype HookFunction(char* path, uint64_t vaddr, ftype replace);
```

Then your `Load` function would look like this:

```
void Load(){
    orgFunction = HookFunction((char*)"something", 0x50000, orgFunctionHook);
}
```

If you can't modify `HookFunction`, then just use the typedef in the call:

```
void Load(){
    orgFunction = (ftype)HookFunction((char*)"something", 0x50000, (void *)orgFunctionHook);
}
```

Comment: The function "HookFunction" I cant change anything related to it, maby you meant the "orgFunctionHook"?, this still doesn't solve the issue as the defintion of the HookFunction cant be changed.

Comment: @SchevenzRs See my edit.  Just use the correct type in the cast.

Comment: Seems it have done the effect, Giving it a runtime test and letting you know the result,
Good explaination on your solution.

Comment: you can also use `decltype` to avoid the need to do typedef manually